# Is it correct to put wordpress php shortcode hook inside an if statement in which the if statement is the response of a post method?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api, wordpress-shortcode, wordpress-hook

This is the WordPress php code I am planning to implement. The code is a plugin that post a form data to external Api. The plan is I want the success response to be displayed on WordPress Front-end using shortcodes. Currently i don't have an external api to test it but i am also not if this the right way to get what i want so is it? Thanks in advance.

```
add_action('wpforms_process_complete', 'wpairform_api_sender', 10, 4);
function wpairform_api_sender($fields, $entry, $form_data, $entry_id)
{
    //if form ID is 1
    if ($form_data['id'] == 10240) {

        $api_url = 'https://hook.integromat.com/tzeseygrctyxjbsxfp7psbbkt40j8tc2';
        $body = array(
            'text'      => $fields['1']['value'],
            
        );
        $response = wp_remote_post($api_url, array('body' => $body));
        
        if( is_wp_error( $response )){
            $error_message = $response->get_error_message();
            return "Something went wrong: $error_message";
        }

        if( 200 !== wp_remote_retrieve_response_code( $response )){
            return;
        }

        if (200 === wp_remote_retrieve_response_code( $response )) {
            //$response_body = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response );
            //var_dump($response_body->message);
            function github_issues_func($atts)
            {
            return  wp_remote_retrieve_body($response);
            }
            add_shortcode("github_issues", "github_issues_func");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is to get that response from the API and show it on your Front End, you can save that in a transient instead of generating a shortcode each time the form runs, you can read more about transients [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/apis/handbook/transients/)